# How do I combine stackoverflow's tags

Tags: discussion, tags

Probably a silly question, but I cannot see it.
How do I search for stackoverflow questions that have, for example, both a "junit" and a "logging" tags set ?
Combing the tags with "obvious suspects" (" ", "+", "&", "and", etc.) does not work for me.

Answer (score 2):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/junit+logging

does work for me. Simply use `+` in the URL and a space in the search box. So for this example, just type

```
[junit] [tagging]
```

into the search box.

Comment: one caveat: if any of the tags contains a plus you must escape it, and you *must* use spaces to delimit

Comment: Just a question though: *How* exactly is a literal `+` escaped in the search box? The obvious `%2b` didn't work, `\+` or `++` don't work either. Am I missing something here?

Comment: I was referring to the /questions/tagged syntax, sorry if I wasn't clear

Comment: Well, but typing `[foo+bar]` into the search box also splits into the tags »foo« and »bar« ... so apparently no escaping can save a `+` in a tag from being interpreted wrongly?

Answer (score 0):

see this blog entry:

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/10/tags-and-tags-or-tags/